How much salt is dangerous for copper pipes
I am considering getting an ion-exchange water softener for my home, as we have very hard water. While researching it, I have read in some places that the additional sodium that is added to the water may cause problems for copper pipes (corrosion / pitting, and eventually creating leaks).
The water we currently have has the following measurements:

Hardness: 16 dH° (we live in Germany)
Calcium: 94.2 mg/L
Magnesium: 10.3 mg/L
Sodium: 25.7 mg/L

And from the company I am speaking with, we should expect an additional 8 mg/L of sodium per "dH°" that is removed, and typically you aim to bring it down to ~6 dH°, which means ultimately we would have something like 105.7 mg/L of sodium going into our house.
My question is basically: how much sodium content in water is dangerous for copper pipes or other parts of our plumbing (e.g. water heater)

Another question that should go along with this is: "How much sodium content in water is dangerous to our bodies and our health?"

BTW, pure copper is not attacked by salt water as much as brass, or copper with soldered joints, due to electrolytic corrosion. Perhaps a system that does not use ion exchange might be better, e.g., reverse osmosis.

On the human health question, I know the regulations in my area set a limit of 200 mg/L, so ~106 is well within the limits

Regarding reverse osmosis, my understanding is that they're not that suitable for filtering all the water in the house, and they're better suited to e.g. just installing under the tap or something.

Anecdotally, my house, with quite hard water, has had a water softener for over 30 years and we’ve had no significant problems with our copper piping.

Conversely, in hard water areas, minerals will build up in the lines, particularly the hot side, and eventually require replacement. I lived in two houses in hard water areas where the hot water pressure under flow was significantly lower than cold.
